# How to make the height of a div match the height of the monitor

Tags: css, height

I am trying to change the color of a HTML page in my Angular app.

I have tried to set the `height` of the div to 100% as you can see below, but the div is still not reaching the bottom of the screen.

Here is my latest attempt:

HTML:

```
<div class="full-height">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #373F51;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/welcome']">Welcome</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-height {
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

I read this was a solution on W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_div_full_height.asp)

But this is what's currently being displayed:

[image: screenGrab]

Can someone please tell me how I can make this div fit the entire screen? It will need to be responsive also. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `min-height` and a value in `vh` (*Viewport Height*) unit

```
.full-height {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There's a small bit of white space at the bottom now & the scroll bar appears on the right-hand side. Is there any way around these 2 issues?

Comment: @user9847788 that's most probably because you need to subtract a specific amount of PX (some header height?) - cannot say without seeing the entire example.

Comment: In my angular app, there are no HTML tags in the `app.component.html` file. All that is there is the code I posted above. In this case, what would be my `html` class & my `body` class?

Comment: @user9847788 inspect your page and try to detect which element forces (probably due to some margins) the layout to have a bottom gap. Otherwise, `100vh` is 100vh and there should be no gap.